# How to get http body of call.reponse in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I build a web server with Ktor, and want to cache API method result. But I don't know how to get the response body from call.response. Code like below

```kotlin
fun Application.module(){

    // before method was called
    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features) {
        val cache = redis.get("cache")
        if(cache) {
            call.respond(cache)
        }

        return @intercept finish()
    }
    
    // after method was called
    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Fallback) {
        // TODO, how to get call.response.body
        redis.set("cache", call.response.body)
    }
}
```

If I can't get the response body, Any other solution to cache the result of an API method in Ktor?

Comment: where does your `call` define

Comment: @GuanHongHuang `call` Is a lambda parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside an interceptor, for the `ApplicationCallPipeline.Features` phase you can add a phase just before the `ApplicationSendPipeline.Engine` and intercept it to retreive a response body (`content`):

```
val phase = PipelinePhase("phase")
call.response.pipeline.insertPhaseBefore(ApplicationSendPipeline.Engine, phase)
call.response.pipeline.intercept(phase) { response ->
    val content: ByteReadChannel = when (response) {
        is OutgoingContent.ByteArrayContent -> ByteReadChannel(response.bytes())
        is OutgoingContent.NoContent -> ByteReadChannel.Empty
        is OutgoingContent.ReadChannelContent -> response.readFrom()
        is OutgoingContent.WriteChannelContent -> GlobalScope.writer(coroutineContext, autoFlush = true) {
            response.writeTo(channel)
        }.channel
        else -> error("")
    }

    // Do something with content
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I copy your code and paste into the callback function of `intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Fallback)`, but the interceptor doesn't execute. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: The `ApplicationCallPipeline.Fallback` phase's interceptors are executed only if a call wasn't handled.

Comment: I had been trying many times, but `Fallback` was called every time, even though the call was handled. And also, the phase's interceptor wasn't executed.
Complete code: 
https://replit.com/@gtfhxy/ktor-pipeline-sample#src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt

Comment: I am unable to see your code. Could you please share it via Github gist?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gtfhxy/35458fb30f9cd1e8b964440819705d75

Comment: You are right. It works only if I add my code to the `ApplicationCallPipeline.Features` phase interceptor. Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/9877fab723ff778d08cd76871a46b303. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, It works, That is what I want, thank you very much.